# Springboot: Directly Upload the Image to Azure BlobClient without writing to OS first

Tags: java, azure, image, file-upload, awt

I have generated an image thumbnail which I'm trying to store in azure. BlobClient need the data to be of type "BinaryData" so I wrapped it as:

```
myBlobClient.upload(BinaryData.fromObject(thumbnailImage));
```

The code snippet is this:

```
    RenderedImage thumbnailImage = CommonUtils.generateImageThumbnail(newFilePath + '?' + thumbnailFileSasToken);
    String thumbnailFileName = CommonUtils.removeFileExtension(fileName) + "_preview." + extension;
    String thumbnailFilePath = "./tmp/" + thumbnailFileName;
    File tempFile = new File(thumbnailFilePath);
    assert thumbnailImage != null;
    ImageIO.write(thumbnailImage, extension, tempFile);

    if (item == null) {
        sourceBlobName = String.format("%s/%s", savedOrder.getOrderNo(), thumbnailFileName);
    } else {
        sourceBlobName = String.format("%s/%s/%s", savedOrder.getOrderNo(), item.getItemNo(), thumbnailFileName);
    }
    BlobClient myBlobClient = fileService.getBlobClient(sourceBlobName);
    myBlobClient.upload(BinaryData.fromStream(new FileInputStream(tempFile)));
    return  myBlobClient;
```

Helper Methods:

```
public static BufferedImage convertToBufferedImage(Image image)
    {
        BufferedImage newImage = new BufferedImage(
                image.getWidth(null), image.getHeight(null),
                BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        Graphics2D g = newImage.createGraphics();
        g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
        g.dispose();
        return newImage;
    }

    public static RenderedImage generateImageThumbnail(String filePath) {
        try {
            BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new URL(filePath).openStream());
            Image scaledImage = image.getScaledInstance(300, 300, Image.SCALE_DEFAULT);
            return convertToBufferedImage(scaledImage);
        } catch(IOException ex){
            log.error(ex.getMessage());
        }
        return null;
    }
```

The exception I get on the line myBlobClient.upload is:

> java.io.UncheckedIOException:
> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Invalid
> type definition for type `sun.awt.image.IntegerInterleavedRaster`:
> Failed to construct BeanSerializer for [simple type, class
> sun.awt.image.IntegerInterleavedRaster]:
> (java.lang.IllegalArgumentException) Failed to call `setAccess()` on
> Field 'sampleModel' due to
> `java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException`, problem: Unable to
> make field protected java.awt.image.SampleModel
> java.awt.image.Raster.sampleModel accessible: module java.desktop does
> not "opens java.awt.image" to unnamed module @4fb3ee4e (through
> reference chain: java.awt.image.BufferedImage["raster"])

**Update**
So I found a way to write the file first and convert it into InputStream which then uploads. Is there a way to bypass writing the file first and directly upload it?

**New Attempt**

```
String thumbnailName = CommonUtils.removeFileExtension(fileName) + "_preview." + extension;
String thumbnailPath = "./tmp/" + thumbnailName;
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
File tempFile = new File(thumbnailPath);
if (imageThumbnail != null) {
    ImageIO.write(imageThumbnail, extension, baos);
}
sourceBlobName = item == null ? String.format("%s/%s", savedOrder.getOrderNo(), thumbnailName)
                : String.format("%s/%s/%s", savedOrder.getOrderNo(), item.getItemNo(), thumbnailName);

BlobClient myBlobClient = fileService.getBlobClient(sourceBlobName);
myBlobClient.upload(BinaryData.fromObject(baos));
return  myBlobClient;
```

Comment: does `BinaryData.fromObject` know how to turn raster data (`RenderedImage thumbnailImage`) into compressed image data (jpeg, png, ...)? -- looks to me like your code doesn't even reach any azure-specific code... it fails to create the BinaryData already

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz Thanks. Yes I noticed BinaryData.fromObject is failing. I have updated the logic but I would like to bypass the file writing logic and directly upload the file. Would this be possible?

Comment: ImageIO can write to some kind of buffer object too, right? something that satisfies the File interface but doesn't make a file?

Comment: The exception seems to be the result of an outdated version of the code in the question. If so, I strongly suggest to remove it to avoid confusion. And yes, you can write to a `ByteArrayOutputStream` if you like, to avoid the file.

Comment: So I tried using ByteArrayOutputSteam. The file uploaded to azure as well (Code attached). But when I read the file the image viewer wasn't able to open it.